# Headphones not being detected on ubuntu 16.10

Tags: asus, 16.10, headphones

I'm having trouble getting the headphone jack to work on Ubuntu 16.10.
Laptop is Asus E402SA.

I have checked a few other threads for fixes on the alsa.conf file, but none have seemed to fix it.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,